measure subtotal in Power Pivot
I have created a PowerPivot table for employees to check how many evening or morning shifts they had per month
created table
The Deviation is a measure if the % of evening shifts is lover than 25 or higher than 75
deviation formula
So far all good :) but when I collapse the table, I get the deviation as 0 for all Stores
subtotals
I have tried different calculations based on CALCULATE, FILTER, COUNTROWS but nothing works.
I would need to sum up all deviations by Stores so I would get the overview as well
overview table
